# URL amigável para formulário GET (busca) no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-rotas, url-amigável

**Minha dúvida é o seguinte:** tenho um formulário de busca (GET), e gostaria de saber como ao executar o submit enviar esses parâmetros para o URL de maneira amigável.

Obs.: os parâmetros não são obrigatórios.

**Formulário**:

```html
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'neighborhoods.city', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'get')) }}

      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2">
        {{ Form::select('state_id', $states, 0, array('class' => 'form-control input-lg', 'id' => 'states')) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8" id="cidades">
        {{ Form::select('city_id', $cities, 0, array('class' => 'form-control input-lg', 'disabled' => true)) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2">
        {{ Form::submit('Buscar', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block btn-submit')) }}
      </div>

      {{-- Form::text('search', Input::old('search'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Digite aqui o que você está procurando. Ex.: Encanador'))--}}
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automaticamente eu não sei se há alguma maneira, acredito que não.

O que pode fazer é, percorrer todos os elementos do formulário com javascript, montar a url, e fazer o browser redirecionar para a url com os filtros montados.

Para ficar de modo amigável, pode fazer no formato de named routes: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Poderia ser algo do tipo:

```js
$("form input, form select").each(function(){
    arr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

Outra maneira é utilizar session para os filtros, assim não precisa passar parâmetros por GET, e nem fazer um POST a cada página aberta.

Comment: Foi o que pensei também, não gosto muito de depender de js, mas aparentemente é a melhor solução.

Comment: Se eu não entendi errado, quando você está falando Session é literalmente colocar os dados na sessão?

Comment: Exato, ai vc atualiza os dados na sessão somente quando receber uma requisição via POST. Porém se vc precisa que os dados fiquem numa url, para que possa ser compartilhada já filtrada, ai não tem jeito, ou vc faz da forma que falei com JS, ou deixa no formato padrão gerado pelo form

Answer (score 2):

Eu quando se trata de uma Busca, eu utilizo o GET convencional, mas caso você necessite de uma pesquisa (Amigável) , uma sugestão seria, vc criar uma página para tratar a requisição da Busca, redirecionando para o resultado da busca com o modelo Amigavel .

Exemplo:
Submete via Post ou GET -> **busca?nome=1&param2=teste**
redireciona para
**busca/1/teste

busca/nome/teste/param2/teste**

Ai depende da sua necessidade.

Comment: O problema pra mim ai é o seguinte: qual o correto? Existe uma boa prática visando URL amigáveis, ou fazer uma busca assim é "tolerável"?

Comment: Não vejo problemas numa busca assim, tanto é que sites como americanas, submarino e etc geram links bem mais "feios" do que esse padrão de url gerada pelo GET. Ai vai de gosto, e da necessidade mesmo (cliente pediu) :)

Comment: esse esquema de redirecionar não é legal... apenas gera mais processos e tráfego.. Uma URL de busca pelo método GET  , nada mais é que uma URL comum.. Se quer o site SEO friendly, o ideal é enviar já no formato amigável. També desaconselhável enviar POST misturado com GET..

Answer (score -3):

Você precisa que estes parâmetros sejam passados por URL?
Porque tenho busca em meu site, e uso da seguinte forma meu método:

downloads/bannersaldo

```php
public function postBusca() {
    $word = Input::get('word');

    $articles = Article::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')
        ->orWhere('body', 'LIKE', '%'.$word.'%')
        ->paginate(6);

    return View::make('articles.busca', compact('articles'));
}
```

Os dados da busca são passados na variável e paginadas. Minha URL fica `www.meusite.com/busca`, apenas.

Comment: Não tenho necessidade dos parâmetros na URL, tanto que atualmente é feito utilizando POST. Porém da sua maneira (baseado no seu código) é insegura. De qualquer forma entendi o que você quis dizer. Obrigado.